# Cannot return the address of a cell range from one function to another, I get an 'object required' error

Tags: excel, vba, object

I get an 'object required' error when I try to return the value of a range from one function to another function. I read the other answers about 'object required' but I cannot figure out how that relates to my code. Forgive me but I'm new to VBA. Here's my code:

```
Function functionOne()
    Dim r As Range
    Workbooks("workbook1.xls").Activate
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Set r = GetRange("A1")
    Application.Goto r
End Function

Function GetRange(strStart As String) As Variant
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Set rng1 = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    Set rng2 = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    Set rng3 = Range([strStart], Cells(rng1.Row, rng2.Column))
    GetRange = rng3.Value
End Function
```

The 'object required' error happens at the `Set r = GetRange("A1")`in functionOne(). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your  `GetRange` function to return `Range` object:

```
Function GetRange(strStart As String) As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Set rng1 = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    Set rng2 = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    Set rng3 = Range([strStart], Cells(rng1.Row, rng2.Column))
    Set GetRange = rng3
End Function
```